# jQuery div.html() update does not update on browser after first change

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a div on a page that is updated via a form and changed via an AJAX call. 
When the form is edited and saved, the `$('#element').html(new_html)` works fine in the success call and changes on the browser. 
However, if I change the data again and call the **AJAX** script more than once, it will return the changed data to the success function, and updates the va new_html correctly, but the `$('#element').html(new_html)` does NOT update the **DOM** or browser. Only on the first call, after that an entire page refresh is required.

Why would `$('#element).html(new_html)` change the display on the browser on the first call, but not on any subsequent calls?

Is this a caching issue?

Comment: It will, probably you make it wrong

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: Actually it's a lot of code, it's a very complex page, however, I did find my error and it was in my code. I was forgetting to change one variable on the first change that set the index of the div being updated, so all future changes to it went to a non-existent div.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved and was a programming error. I'd delete the question, but since some have tried to help already just wanted to leave it here with my answer.